# Standard Big query Not removing String

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to filter out "null" from a string column using Standard Big query and for whatever reason it is not being filtered out

so my where statement goes:

```
where d_transaction_dt <> "null"
```

d_transaction_dt is a string column that I'm trying to cast as date and remove anything in there that is "null"

I'm getting the error: Invalid date: 'null'

Please help..

Comment: Could provide a complete sample query that fails? (Just `SELECT * FROM (tablename) WHERE StringField <> "null"` works for me.)

Comment: I tried that and for whatever reason I'm still getting an error

Comment: Again, please provide a complete sample query. Until we can reproduce the problem, it'll be really hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Is it literally the string "null", or is the field null?  If you're doing something like a [SAFE_CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#casting) to convert strings to a DATE type, you're probably getting NULL values.

```
WHERE d_transaction_dt <> "null"
```

is an entirely different filter predicate than

```
WHERE d_transaction_dt IS NOT NULL
```